# D3 Brushing reusable

Tags: d3.js

I tried to make Mike Bostocks example of focus + context via brushing (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) make reusable following his convention: bost.ocks. org/mike/chart/ [sorry, I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links yet]

I modified his brushing example a little bit, worked perfect, but I'm failing on making that reusable now. Whenever I try to select something on the context chart, the focus chart zooms in - but never out again.

The code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/VoEL1eFJI1Xnajzf82Zq?p=preview

Can anyone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong scale for the brush -- it should be the one assigned to the context chart, `xScaleTimeLine` in your case. Fixed example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/98SWQhWJauy3ScbwKwRN?p=preview).

On a general note, including data processing (such as parsing dates and formatting numbers) in your reusable chart component is not best practice. I would first process the data itself and then pass it to the chart component such that no further processing needs to be done. A chart component like this can be used even if the data processing required is quite complex (e.g. nesting).

Comment: Thanks a lot Lars, also for the hint on data processing.